# What is the type of language for

Tags: computation-theory

```
{xwx|x€{a,b}+,w€{a,b}+}
```

Is it regular or CFG? As I see it I can write it as `(a+b)(a+b)+(a+b)`. So it should be regular, but I am not sure.

Comment: The `x` is the same at the beginning and at the end, so your expression is not equivalent since it doesn’t remember the first `x`. It’s not regular.

Answer (score 1):

Just as poke said, this language cannot be regular, since `x` appears twice. It is a context-free language, because a pushdown automaton can accept it by pushing a's and b's in the first `x` and popping it them the second `x`. A classical example for contextfree languages is the [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), which consists of strings with correctly nested parentheses. And it is also right that your two expressions are not equivalent.